# Merge two git branches I don't own

Tags: git

This question probably has an obvious answer. There are two abandoned git repositories I would like to merge locally, on my hard drive. GitHub says they can be merged automatically. I've tried multiple tutorials but they all ask me for GitHub credentials as if it was going to push the changes to GitHub. So how can I merge two repos locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done:

```
git clone <url-for-first-repos>
git remote add second url-for-second-repos
git fetch other
```

Now you have all objects from both repositories and can proceed with an attempt at merging. To be safe, let's do that on a new branch:

```
git checkout master              # master from first repository
git checkout -b both             # new branch "both"
git merge second/master           # merge the master from the second repository
```

After conflict resolution, which might be substantial if both of the repositories branched off their common ancestor a long time back, you will have merged them.

Of course, this assumes that they *did* branch off of a common ancestor. If they are completely unrelated, then there will be no useful merge.